# Recursion in python(Methods and Classes)

Tags: python, class, oop, recursion, methods

I am very new to `OOP`, and python; I was trying to implement a recursive function where I give input [[5,6],[2,3]]. The function should print 5,6, 2,3 and then recursively 5 and 6, and 2 and 3 .....

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input
        self.left = self.input[0]
        self.right = self.input[1]

    def merg(self, param1=0, param2=0):
        if len(self.input) > 0:
            print(self.input[0])
            print(self.input[1])
            self.merg(self.left)
            self.merg(self.right)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_input = [[5,6],[2,3]]
    new_input = Test(new_input)
    new_input.merg()
```

**Desired Output**

```
[5,6]
[2,3]
5
6
2
3
```

**error:**
`RecursionError:` maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object at line `self.merg(self.left)`

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with `param1` or `param2`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of recursion you are trying to implement requires that the values passes each time are reduced.

Maybe something like this?

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.input = values
        
    def merg(self):
        self._merg(self.input)

    def _merg(self, values):
        try:       # the base case is when the object passed has no length, and raises a TypeError - we catch that and exit.
            if len(values) > 0:
                left, right = values
                print(left)
                print(right)
                self._merg(left)
                self._merg(right)
        except TypeError:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_input = [[5,6],[2,3]]
    new_input = Test(new_input)
    new_input.merg()
```

#### output:

```
[5, 6]
[2, 3]
5
6
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the best I could do keeping the structure you had initially:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input
        self.left = self.input[0]
        self.right = self.input[1]

    def merg(self, param1=""):
        if param1 == "":
            param1 = self.input
        if not isinstance(param1, int):
            print(param1[0])
            print(param1[1])
            self.merg(param1[0])
            self.merg(param1[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_input = [[5,6],[2,3]]
    test_obj = Test(new_input)
    test_obj.merg()
```

I'm not using self.left and self.right, simply because you don't need to define them in the constructor, at least not for this usage.

Moreover, in the code you posted, you totally ignored param1 and param2, which are needed.

This is the output I get from this code :

```
[5, 6]
[2, 3]
5
6
2
3
```

---

**FURTHER EXPLAINING**

```
if param1 == "":
    param1 = self.input
```

This "if" basically checks if the function was called with parameters. If not, the param1 variable should be the object's input variable which it was initiated with.

```
if not isinstance(param1, int):
            print(param1[0])
            print(param1[1])
            self.merg(param1[0])
            self.merg(param1[1])
```

This if checks if the parameter is an int or not. If it isn't, it enters the block. That way, the code stops after it has printed all four numbers.

Please tell me if you need more explaining.